# Problem with running KafkaContainer (testcontainers) in Jenkins

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, testcontainers

Hi everyone who are reading this!
I have java app with a test, containing:

```java
        kafka = new KafkaContainer(
                DockerImageName.parse("harbor-main.test.com/devbird/confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.2")
                        .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("confluentinc/cp-kafka")
        kafka.withEmbeddedZookeeper().start();
...
```

which I build using maven container in jenkins.

```
       mvn clean install
```

I am using Jenkins, running in Kubernetes.

Agent file, used in Jenkinsfile

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  namespace: project-jenkins
spec:
  containers:
    - name: maven
      image: harbor-main.test.com/maven-jdk17-git:latest
      command:
        - cat
      tty: true
      volumeMounts:
        - name: maven-cache
          mountPath: /root/.m2/repository
    - name: dind-daemon
      image: harbor-main.test.com/docker:dind-rootless
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
        readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
      command: 
        - cat
      tty: true
      volumeMounts:
        - name: docker-socket
          mountPath: /run/user/1001/docker.sock
  volumes:
    - name: docker-socket
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: maven-cache
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: maven-cache
```

I am getting error in jenkins:

```
08:12:51  23/03/16 08:12:51 WARN TestcontainersConfiguration: Attempted to read Testcontainers configuration file at file:/root/.testcontainers.properties but the file was not found. Exception message: FileNotFoundException: /root/.testcontainers.properties (No such file or directory)
08:12:52  23/03/16 08:12:51 ERROR DockerClientProviderStrategy: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
08:12:52    UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (Could not find unix domain socket). Root cause NoSuchFileException (/var/run/docker.sock)As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue.
08:12:52  See https://www.testcontainers.org/on_failure.html for more details.
08:12:52  Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.228 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

Did I miss some extra configuration for testcontainers?

Is my agent file correct?

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out what was the problem.

**So working solution is:**

In tests:

```java
        kafka = new KafkaContainer(
                DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.2"))
                .waitingFor(Wait.forLogMessage(".*started.*\\n", 1));
                kafka.withEmbeddedZookeeper()
                .start();
```

In Jenkins pipeline (in maven container):

```
sh('cp src/main/resources/.testcontainers.properties ~/.testcontainers.properties')
```

Content of the src/main/resources/.testcontainers.properties file:

```
hub.image.name.prefix=harbor-main.test.com/
checks.disable=false
```

Jenkins agent yaml file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  namespace: project-jenkins
spec:
  containers:
    - name: maven
      image: harbor-main.test.com/maven-jdk17-git:latest
      env:
        - name: DOCKER_HOST
          value: unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock
        - name: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR
          value: ""
      command:
        - cat
      tty: true
      volumeMounts:
        - name: maven-cache
          mountPath: /root/.m2/repository
        - name: docker-socket
          mountPath: /var/run
    - name: dind-daemon
      image: harbor-main.test.com/docker:dind-rootless
      env:
        - name: DOCKER_HOST
          value: unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock
        - name: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR
          value: ""
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
        readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
      command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - |
          dockerd-entrypoint.sh &
          sleep 5
          chmod 666 /run/user/1000/docker.sock
          tail -f /dev/null
      tty: true
      volumeMounts:
    - name: docker-socket
      emptyDir: {}
      volumeMounts:
        - name: docker-socket
          mountPath: /run/user/1000
  volumes:
    - name: docker-socket
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: maven-cache
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: maven-cache
```

In my case userID was 1000. You can get it using command:

```bash
kubectl -n <namespace> exec -it <podname> -c <containername> -- id -u
```

I spent couple of days to solve it, hopefully somebody will find it useful.